# Trigger API call when cell is edited

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

Working with a **Google Sheets** where every line includes an **ID** and a **picklist** value. Example: [Google Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAVhj.png).

What I am trying to do is run a custom function when someone edits the **picklist** cell.  The function takes two arguments, the value from the ID and the picklist cell of the same line, then performs a HTTP POST request to update the record in our CRM.

```
//When STAGE cell on Google Sheet is updated, run this function:

function updateProjectStage(status, id) {
  var baseURL = 'https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/json/Potentials/updateRecords?authtoken=xxx&scope=crmapi&id=', // see docs https://www.zoho.com/crm/help/api/updaterecords.html
      recordID = id, // building id from A column
      stage = '<Potentials><row no="1"><FL val="Stage">' + status + '</FL></row></Potentials>'; // status from B column

  var postURL = baseURL + recordID + '&xmlData=' + stage;
  Logger.log(postURL);

  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(postURL); // update record in crm
  var sanitizedResponse = JSON.parse(response.getContentText()); // get confirmation/failure
  Logger.log(sanitizedResponse);
}
```

I don't know how to run the function for this picklist type of cell - I cannot just input `=updateProjectStage(status, id)` into the cell like I am used to doing because it errors out.

Example:  [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6T0pi.png).

Is this even possible?

Comment: It seems like you're not having any trouble with your Go code, just how to make an API call from Google Sheets, so this may be better suited to [Super User](https://superuser.com/).

Comment: Well this has to be written in golang, so I don't know why you'd say that - it's exactly what I'm having trouble with.  I don't even know what to write; surely there must be some helper functions to handle events - but can they be used in a Google Sheets custom function script?

Comment: Google Sheets scripts run in the browser, Go does not. I thought you were running this Go code in some kind of service, maybe I'm not understanding your question well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your answer lies in capturing the edit event when the user modifies any cell on the sheet. The user can modify **any** cell, of course. Your job is to determine if that cell is in the range you care about. The `onEdit` event can be captured using this function:

```
function onEdit(eventObj) {
  //--- check if the edited cell is in range, then call your function
  //    with the appropriate parameters
}
```

The object passed into the event describes the cell that was edited. So we set up a "check range" and then make a comparison of that range to whichever cell was edited. Here's the function:

```
function isInRange(checkRange, targetCell) {
  //--- check the target cell's row and column against the given
  //    checkrange area and return True if the target cell is
  //    inside that range
  var targetRow = targetCell.getRow();
  if (targetRow < checkRange.getRow() || targetRow > checkRange.getLastRow()) return false;

  var targetColumn = targetCell.getColumn();
  if (targetColumn < checkRange.getColumn() || targetColumn > checkRange.getLastColumn()) return false;

  //--- the target cell is in the range!
  return true;
}
```

The full event function for the edit event would be

```
function onEdit(eventObj) {
  //--- you could set up a dynamic named range for this area to make it easier
  var checkRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B10");  
  if (isInRange(checkRange, eventObj.range)) {
    //--- the ID cell is on the same row, one cell to the left
    var idCell = eventObj.range.offset(0,-1);
    //--- the status cell is the one that was edited
    var statusCell = eventObj.range;
    updateProjectStage(statusCell, idCell);
  }
}
```

Here's the whole thing all together:

```
function isInRange(checkRange, targetCell) {
  Logger.log('checking isInRange');

  //--- check the target cell's row and column against the given
  //    checkrange area and return True if the target cell is
  //    inside that range
  var targetRow = targetCell.getRow();
  if (targetRow < checkRange.getRow() || targetRow > checkRange.getLastRow()) return false;
  Logger.log('not outside the rows');

  var targetColumn = targetCell.getColumn();
  if (targetColumn < checkRange.getColumn() || targetColumn > checkRange.getLastColumn()) return false;
  Logger.log('not outside the columns');

  //--- the target cell is in the range!
  return true;
}

function onEdit(eventObj) {
  //--- you could set up a dynamic named range for this area to make it easier
  var checkRange = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("B2:B10");  
  if (isInRange(checkRange, eventObj.range)) {
    Logger.log('cell is in range');
    //--- the ID cell is on the same row, one cell to the left
    var idCell = eventObj.range.offset(0,-1);
    //--- the status cell is the one that was edited
    var statusCell = eventObj.range;
    updateProjectStage(statusCell, idCell);
  }  else {
    Logger.log('must be outside the range');
  }
}

function updateProjectStage(status, id) {
  Logger.log('we are updating');
}
```

Comment: Hmm, I mostly got it working following your logic but the final function *updateProjectStage* isn't firing off the HTTP Post request.  I'm getting some sort of **Invalid Ticket Id** error.  If I log the *sanitizedResponse* it prints to the logs perfectly - I can manually input it into a new tab and it'll update the CRM record.  But it's not firing that url.  Hmm, what could it be... ?!

Comment: `{"response":{"error":{"code":"4834","message":"Invalid Ticket Id"},"uri":"/crm/private/json/Potentials/updateRecords"}}`

Comment: It sounds like this is a separate question. The example I posted should get you to the `updateProjectStage` function in order to make your HTTP Post request. You can log the `status` and `id` parameters and/or the whole `postURL` to verify the request format and information. But it sounds like it's more of an issue with your data accessing your private account on the crm server, which I can't help you with given the information above.

Comment: Yes, you're right.  I've gotten everything working using your solution, but you had the two variables mixed up.  The `statusCell` is actually `idCelll` and vise versa. If you could edit those I'll go ahead and mark this question as solved. *thumbs_up*

Comment: The answer has been edited and updated. Sorry for the mixup