# Google Sheet Script Triggers issues

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I was trying to create a script for google sheet that counts certain colors and it seems to be working perfectly, but when I tried to make a trigger for it, this is when I start to get problems.

I created the trigger with the OnEdit() event, but everytime I edit the table i get this exception "interval not found". So, if I want it to work correcly, I have to cut and paste the formula on the table (Because the trigger isn't working).

This is my code:

```
function countColor(countRange) {
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(countRange);

var rangeWidth = range.getWidth();

var bg = range.getBackgrounds();
var score = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < rangeWidth; i++)
{
  if (bg[0][i] == "#38761d")
  {
    score += 1;
  }      
  else if (bg[0][i] == "#ffff00")
  {
    score = score + 0.5;
  }      
  else if (bg[0][i] == "#274e13")
  {
    score += 1.5;
  }
  
}
return score;  
};
```

1 - So I want to know why the trigger isn't working correcly.

2 - I would like also to know, how to do this--> when I copy and paste the formula in another cell, these correspond to the row in which I have pasted it. (just like normal tables do). For example is the range was a1:b1 in the first cell, when I copy it on the second cell it would be a2:b2

Comment: Part of your problem might be how you're passing in the range to your function from the sheet. See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/58179) for details to make sure.

Comment: This solved my problem with the second issue! ty!!!!

Comment: The other detail to making the `onEdit` trigger work for you is making sure you're correctly identifying which cells were edited, making sure it's the area you want. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51792928/4717755) shows how.

Comment: Modifying the code a bit, it really worked for me!!!! thanks!!! I was hoping to create some kind of interaction where you could just "restart" the function on the table, but instead, I just verify which row was edited and modify cell where I know the function is.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases time based triggers cannot be  used with functions that accept parameters.  In your case the parameter `countrange` will probably be populated with the triggers event object which will likely result in some very weird behavior.

Functions that you write to be used in cells are called custom functions in google apps script and you cannot run custom function from a trigger.

[Custom Functions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/sheets/functions?hl=en#getting_started)

Comment: Ya I though that it had something to do with the accepted parameters, I though there could be a way to make this cells works automatically. Thanks!!!!